# Shows Permission Denial error for titanium appcelerator

Tags: appcelerator-mobile

I used the below code

var findus = Ti.Contacts.getPeopleWithName('john');

and the error i got is

uncaught error: permission denial : reading com.android.providers.contacts.contactsprovider2 uri content://com.android.contacts/data from pid=277, uid=10045 requires android.permission. READ_CONTACTS

But i have placed the below lines in tiapp.xml

```
  <android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> <manifest>
  <uses-   permission android:name="com.get.permission.READ_CONTACTS"
  android:protectionLevel="signature"/> </manifest> </android>
```

Android version : 2.2 sdk : 1.8.2 os

please help on this issue.........

Comment: Did you [requestAuthorization](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Contacts-method-requestAuthorization)?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you've not requested an authorization.

Please request an authorization before accessing contacts. The following example is from Titanium docs (http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Contacts):

```
var performAddressBookFunction = function(){
    var findus = Ti.Contacts.getPeopleWithName('john');
};
var addressBookDisallowed = function(){alert('Sorry');};
if (Ti.Contacts.contactsAuthorization == Ti.Contacts.AUTHORIZATION_AUTHORIZED){
    performAddressBookFunction();
} else if (Ti.Contacts.contactsAuthorization == Ti.Contacts.AUTHORIZATION_UNKNOWN){
    Ti.Contacts.requestAuthorization(function(e){
        if (e.success) {
            performAddressBookFunction();
        } else {
            addressBookDisallowed();
        }
    });
} else {
    addressBookDisallowed();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The name of the permission is "*android*.permission.READ_CONTACTS" rather than "com.get.permission.READ_CONTACTS".

Try the following in your tiapp.xml:

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <manifest>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
  </manifest>
</android>
```